# "Dessert/Desert" is my favorite thing. - Does English word syllable stress change when they are in a sentence or in a paragraph?

Tags: word-meaning, accent, word-stress

Does English word syllable stress change when they are in a sentence or in a larger unit, say, like in a paragraph? I am asking this because I have heard that some languages such as Japanese have accent emphasis changes when the word is followed by some other words. So I kind of wonder whether English has this kind of feature or not.

However, I don't think English has it.
For example, a dessert cannot sound like a desert even if an emphasis is placed in the sentence, in my opinion. Simply put, I believe sentence stress does not do anything to word syllable stress.
But I still need more experienced speakers to help shed light on this topic, because linguistics is not something I am good at.

**Example 1**

> Dessert is my favorite thing.

However you try to emphasize or do something to the sentence, the word dessert cannot be altered to sound like desert.

**Example**

> The suspect was caught by the police.

However you try to emphasize or do something to the sentence, the word suspect cannot be altered to sound like the verb "suspect."

Comment: Any word in a sentence in English can "take" the stress. However, a single word like dessert or desert does not change its individual pronunciation. Those two can be stressed or not.

Answer (score 1):

I love the dessert in summer.

Any word in that sentence can be stressed, which changes the overall idea but do not affect the word dessert.
*I* love the dessert in summer.
I *love* the dessert in summer.
I love *the dessert* in summer.
I love the dessert *in summer*.

The tonic accent for the word dessert does not change in those examples.

*I* love deserts.
I *love* deserts.
I love *deserts*.

deserts is the same in all three what changes is which word is stressed.

As for suspect (verb) and suspect (noun) the same is true but only context will tell which is meant.

I *suspect* he knew the truth. [verb, second syllable takes the tonic accent.]

The **suspect** managed to flee the scene. [noun, first syllable takes the tonic accent.]

Comment: This is correct, except that in AmE we would not likely say "I love **the** dessert in summer". The word "dessert" tends to encompass all desserts. It would be said like this: "I love dessert in summer". If a particular dessert were meant, it would be: "I love **that** dessert in summer" or the particular dessert would be specified, like "I love frozen yogurt in the summer". Not nitpicking here but the sentence as written in the answer is strange/incorrect.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it It is not incorrect. The dessert can already have been established. But that/this is *more* usual, I agree. I love the dessert (you make) in summer.

Comment: "I love the dessert you make in summer" is perfect. "I love the dessert in summer" would rarely be used, and only when speaking of a dessert already established (to your point) and in comparison to some other season, like this: Jack- "I am not fond of the dessert served here in winter." Jill- "I love the dessert in summer." A general statement about the joys of ice cream in the summertime would go like this: "I love dessert in the summer".

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Yes, an already established point. Not much one can teach me about this sort of thing. But thanks anyway.